# Android, how to ignore an already connected WiFi, just like mobile phone forget WiFi

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

**I know the following method can be used, But sometimes that doesn't work.**

```
public void removeNetwork(String sSid){
    WifiConfiguration tempConfig = isExist(sSid);
    if (tempConfig != null) {
        try {
            boolean isRemoved = mWifiManager.removeNetwork(tempConfig.networkId);
            boolean isDisabled = mWifiManager.disableNetwork(tempConfig.networkId);
            boolean isSaved = mWifiManager.saveConfiguration();
            Log.i(TAG, "isRemoved: "+ isRemoved + ", isDisabled" + isDisabled+ ", isSaved" + isSaved);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.i(TAG, "RemoveNetwork Exception: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I know the following method can be used`™? For what?